# Can I prioritize the starling package in FlashDevelop?

Tags: flashdevelop

I'm beginning to use Starling quite frequently, and my preferred IDE is FlashDevelop.

Unfortunately I am getting quite frustrated with FlashDevelop while trying to use Starling. It will assume I am referring to a class in the `flash` packages when in actual fact I want to use those in the `starling` package. Here's an example:

[image]

Once I close the parenthesis, hit space, etc, it will add an `import` statement for `flash.display.Event` at the top.

Can I prioritize the `starling` packages in this auto-complete tool somehow for a given project? Obviously it is currently in alphabetical order.

Comment: I'm not using FlashDevelop at all, but IntelliJ Idea seams to be intelligent enough to learn from its mistakes, setting the more used packages on top. If you start typing event, and pick the one in the Starling package a couple of times, it automatically selects it in the future. Maybe FlashDevelop could do something like that, too? But I can't really help you with this one. Maybe try to include the Starling package yourself. This could trigger this type of intelligence in your editor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no solution at the moment to make FD smarter with Starling - but it's something that is being considered.

Comment: Do you have any sources to add?

Comment: Sources? I'm the developer of FlashDevelop code completion engine.

Comment: Ahh something you should put into your Stack Overflow profile.

Comment: Hey @Philippe! Thanks for the great work on FlashDevelop!!! :)  Just for information, has this option been implemented yet by now?

Thanks.